# How to make a 2D arrow on the screen that always point to a 3d object inside the AR Scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I want to display a 2D arrow on the screen that always moves to point to a 3D object in the AR scene.

The issue is how to measure the angle that should the arrow rotate to point the desired 3D object.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show some code

Answer (score 2):

One strategy is to project the position of your object into screen space.
Then calculate the vector between the position of your arrow and that projected position. You can use this vector to calculate an angle of rotation from, for example, a vertical direction, using the Dot Product, followed by an acos.

Finally, you'd need to do a little cross-product calculation to decide whether the above rotation is clockwise or anticlockwise.

Here is some sample code:

```
    public GameObject Target;

    RectTransform rt;

    void Start()
    {
        rt = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Get the position of the object in screen space
        Vector3 objScreenPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(Target.transform.position);

        // Get the directional vector between your arrow and the object
        Vector3 dir = (objScreenPos - rt.position).normalized;

        // Calculate the angle 
        // We assume the default arrow position at 0° is "up"
        float angle = Mathf.Rad2Deg * Mathf.Acos(Vector3.Dot(dir, Vector3.up));

        // Use the cross product to determine if the angle is clockwise
        // or anticlockwise
        Vector3 cross = Vector3.Cross(dir, Vector3.up);
        angle = -Mathf.Sign(cross.z) * angle;

        // Update the rotation of your arrow
        rt.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(rt.localEulerAngles.x, rt.localEulerAngles.y, angle);
    }
```

For the above code, I suppose that:

- You are only using one main camera, you may need to change this
- Your arrow is on the Canvas, by default pointing upwards (when its rotation is (0, 0, 0))
- You are using a Canvas in Render Mode: Screen Space - Overlay. The above code would be different if the Canvas were in World Space.

Answer (score 1):

As a high-level overview:

- Find direction from UI/view-plane centre to 3D object
- Project direction onto UI/view-plane (using forward as normal vector), and normalize
- Point 2D arrow toward projected direction

Answer (score 1):

Thank You all Guys, I got an Answer for two Situations :
First One: When the two objects are in 3D

```
    public GameObject flesh;
    public GameObject target;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        flesh.transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3( Screen.width/2, Screen.height/2,1));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var dir = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(target.transform.position) - 
        Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(flesh.transform.position);
        var angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        flesh.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
    }
```

Second: When the Flesh is an Image that Has RectTransform, 
, this solution Inspirational from @kevernicus

```
public GameObject Target;

    RectTransform rt;

    void Start()
    {
        rt = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Get the position of the object in screen space
        Vector3 objScreenPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(Target.transform.position);

        // Get the directional vector between your arrow and the object
        Vector3 dir = (objScreenPos - rt.position).normalized;

        float angle = Mathf.Rad2Deg * Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x);


        rt.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Unity's built in [Transform.LookAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) function

Comment: This won't actually work, as screen space and world space are very different. LookAt will neively utilize the screen space object's location as a world space coordinate due to how Unity actualizes things in the scene.

Comment: i used it before but it doesn't work due to the difference between screen and AR world coordination system

Comment: You have to convert screen space to world space and vice-versa. Camera has a method for this `Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint`